# Why image is not displayed in browser?

Tags: html, file, image

below screen shot describes my problem.. The image src is correct as the image can be seen in firebug, but **I am unable to display the image in browser.**

Can anybody tell what I am missing ???

[image]

Comment: is it displayed in any other browser ?

Comment: @XTG : No it is not. I checked on Chrome also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security restrictions in some browsers prevent pages hosted on HTTP from embedding images using `file:` URIs.

Comment: how can i deal with them ?

Comment: Load the images over HTTP.

Comment: Actually image names are fetched from database. How can I load them over http? I haven't done this before locally.

Comment: The source of the image names doesn't matter. The source of the images does. Install a webserver. Use an HTTP URI.

Answer (score -1):

See the solution given below, and see your image path, you will understand it automatically-
[image]

Comment: @Sujit Singh On your firebug, you will find image path is starts with file:// where as my path starts with http://